# Почему не записывается пустой файл в java?

Tags: java, файлы, input, файловая-система, io

Есть код. Я хотел просто записать пустой файл.

```
public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "FileTest0.txt";
        String path = "D://";
        File file = new File(path, fileName);
}
}
```

И не записался файл совсем. В скрытых файлах в директории я его тоже прошерстил - не оказалось его там.
Но стоило сделать минимально не пустой - что-нибудь записать файл через `outputStream` как всё заработало, новый файл в директории нашёлся:

```
public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "FileTest0.txt";
        String path = "D://";
        File file = new File(path, fileName);  
        try(ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))){
            os.writeObject(new String("Долой самодержавие и престолонаследие"));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** почему команда `new File` автоматически не приводит к созданию нового файла? Почему чтобы создать новый файл в директории, нужно обязательно в него что-то записать?

Comment: А Вы пробовали записать в него пустую строку `""`?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов вопрос то не в этом. Я хочу без стрима создать файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `File`, определенный в пакете `java.io`, не работает напрямую с потоками. Его задачей является управление информацией о файлах и каталогах. Хотя на уровне операционной системы файлы и каталоги отличаются, но в Java они описываются одним классом `File`.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
bool created = file.createNewFile();
if (created) {
  System.out.println("File %d created");
} else {
  System.out.println("File %d not created");
}
```

Comment: Даже если я вас и понял, будет здорово если вы ваш вопрос исправите так, чтобы поняли новички, которые зайдут с той же проблемой. Напишите решение с psvm, с исходным куском чтобы школьникам было удобно пользоваться вашим ответом.

Comment: Хотя да, вы правы, файл создался. Перепишите по нормальному ответ, и да принято.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin так пойдет?

Comment: Да, оно. Принято. В тексте, принято выделять кодом слова `java.io`, `File`. В русском SO принято. В английском - не принято. И ещё, если вам не в лом  - две строки добавьте в ответ - кратко, на одно предложение поясните, что за команда createNewFile/